# glGetShaderSource retruns 'true' with length of 3

Tags: c++, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to write a sample workflow using es2 in a C++ unit test.
when doing

```
glCompileShader(vertexShader);
```

I'm getting 0 for `GL_COMPILE_STATUS` flag

```
GLint vertexShaderRes;
glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &vertexShaderRes);
EXPECT_NE(GL_FALSE, vResult) << "glGetShaderiv result is 0";
```

Then I tried to find if I made any error in shader source part

```
GLint vertSrcLen;
glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_SHADER_SOURCE_LENGTH, &vertSrcLen);
EXPECT_NE(0, vertSrcLen) << "shader source len error";
GLchar vertCode[vertSrcLen];
glGetShaderSource(vertexShader, vertSrcLen, NULL, vertCode);
EXPECT_TRUE(false) << "==== vertex shader source ===="<< std::endl
                   << "len: "<< vertSrcLen             << std::endl
                   << vertCode                        << std::endl
                   << "==============================";
```

The output above is

```
Value of: false
  Actual: false
Expected: true
==== vertex shader source ====
len: 3
true
==============================
```

My shader source are defined as below:

```
std::string vertexSource = "/path/to/vertex.glsl"
std::ifstream vertexStream(vertexSource, std::ios::in);
ASSERT_EQ(true, vertexStream.is_open()) << "unable to open vertex shader file";
std::stringstream vertStr;
vertStr << vertexStream.rdbuf();
auto vertStrPtr = (const GLchar*)(vertStr.str()).c_str();
glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertStrPtr, NULL);
```

And the original of this all is I'm getting `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` when calling `glGetAttribLocation();` and here seems something wrong with my shader part. Any idea what's wrong with my code? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why do not use [`glGetShaderInfoLog`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetShaderInfoLog.xhtml) to get the error information log?

Comment: `GLchar vertCode[vertSrcLen];` this code seems to make use of VLAs which is not portable (its a compiler extension)

Comment: "`auto vertStrPtr = (const GLchar*)(vertStr.str()).c_str();`" That's way too many temporaries. It doesn't work.

Comment: That file reading code is much more complicated and convoluted than it should be to the point where im not sure its valid (im in fact pretty sure it isnt because the temp string from the stream goes out of scope too soon).

Comment: @Rabbid76 I'm also trying this after compiling the shader, returned 'infoLog' string have random issue like "0:1: L0001: Unknown character ''(18)" and I think it's not being updated by glGetShaderInfoLog.

Comment: The log is correct because reading the file does not work and you just pass garbage to `glShaderSource`. Read the other comments and do not ignore them.

Comment: Thanks @NicolBolas. I changed another way for passing source code pointer and now it works!

Comment: @Borgleader you're right. I also need to change the way like "`GLchar* vertCode = new GLchar[vertSrcLen];`" and it can read in source code now. Thanks for the help